# Regular Expression not working in Google Sheet (RE2)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to use the following regular expression on Google Sheet:

```
REGEXEXTRACT(Sites!E2,"=(?(?=((.*?)&))\2|(.*))")
```

However, it tells me that it is not a valid regular expression.
I have seen only that the reason is that Google uses RE2, which does not support for lookarounds?
Can anyone help?

Here what I am trying to capture:

https://regex101.com/r/wFub9Y/1

Comment: What do you want to do with these captured values? `REGEXEXTRACT()` only returns the very 1st captured value.

Answer (score 0):

[RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) does not support lookarounds, and it does not support the conditional constructs that is also present in your pattern.

> `(?(cond)true|false)` conditional branch (**NOT SUPPORTED**)

Actually, your pattern matches a `=` char and then either captures any text before the first `&` char, or end of string.

Hence, you may safely use

```
REGEXEXTRACT(Sites!E2, "=([^&]+)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wFub9Y/2). That is, match a `=` and capture all one or more chars other than a `&` char into Group 1 whose value will be returned by the `REGEXEXTRACT` function.